# Eclipse gets NullPointerException when selecting an Android Build as a Build Target for Android Test Project

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, build, target

I'm trying to create a new Android Test Project, and when I get to the point where you select a Build Target, I pick Android 2.2 (but this goes for any Android version I pick). I get a NPE, and then the project won't work. I check the build path and the Android stuff is not included, so it's not getting it.

Comment: Do you have the Android 2.2 Targets in your SDK Manager? You can find them by going in Eclipse `Window->SDK Manager` and checking if you have `SDK Platform` installed for 2.2

Comment: Yes, everything is installed under 2.2. I'm thinking, because I've uninstalled and re-installed Android stuff a few times, I may have moved it and Eclipse is pointing somewhere null, but I don't know where to set that. I've already fixed my environments paths.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed 2.2 then **right click on project** > select **properties** > **Android** > under **Project Build Target** select *Android 2.2* and run your project again.
Let me know if that waorks.

Comment: When I click on Android it says 'the currently displayed page contains invalid values'. And then to get to the page I have to click another section before clicking on Android. And it won't let me add 2.2.

Comment: @user1028497 Provide the snapshots of what is happening at Android tab so I can understand you better.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/207/invalidc.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/invalid2.png/

Comment: Unfortunately, that error box disappears before I can select that option. I was barely able to get the screenshot.

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling android sdk completely and then installing it again, make sure PATH environment variable is set for both java and android sdk. And a suggestion that always keep your android sdk manager updated. And do let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: I've done a complete re-install of eclipse and the android SDK, and still nothing.

Comment: I've tried everything I can. Uninstalling and reinstalling every combination of eclipse and java and android that I can, and nothing works. Driving me nuts.